# Android orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am downloading an image from a server and adding it as left drawable to different buttons. The problem is when I rotate the emulator, all the left drawables of buttons are reloaded.

I also tried adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to manifest file but that doesn't help.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or is there a particular procedure for it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the screen is rotated, the Activity is restarted and all your drawables need to be loaded again.

To stop it from reloading, add this to your manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

This will keep your activity in portrait mode at all times.

If you do wish to be able to change the orientation, you can use these methods

```
onSaveInstanceState
onRestoreInstanceState
```

to keep your drawables in memory and reload them when the activity runs onResume